# Have some church

Tags: meaning

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of "Let's have some church"? The context: it's a musical about God ("Godspell"). I guess it could mean "music", as the characters start singing after that sentence, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please could you [edit] in some more context? The surrounding dialogue would be helpful in understanding what is meant.

Comment: It's probably colloquial. We might say "Let's have some EL&U". Not really standard usage, but it's comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "let's have some (something)" is colloquial, and often used to initiate an activity with a group. In [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams), "let's have some fun" makes up a significant percentage of the results for "let's have some." It'd also be possible to use other objects, like food, drink, or a specific state like quiet:

> Let's have some dinner, Dad. ([The Quest for the All-Seeing Eye](https://books.google.com/books?id=qhysxzLK_MsC&lpg=PA161&ots=bSFiYyvk8j&dq=%22let's%20have%20some%20dinner%22&pg=PA161#v=onepage&q&f=false))
>
> Okay, Fenfang, let's have some beer. ([Twenty Fragments of a Ravenous Youth: A Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=nB4rz8KXa4UC&pg=PA126&dq=%22let%27s%20have%20some%20beer%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ4_S-9NXlAhXlct8KHSZkCawQ6AEwAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22let's%20have%20some%20beer%22&f=false))
>
> "Let's talk for a little while and then let's have some quiet time" ([The Working Parents Handbook](http://%22Let's%20talk%20for%20a%20little%20while%20and%20let's%20have%20some%20quiet%20time%22))

**Let's have some church** fits the same pattern. It feels colloquial because "some church" is an unusual collocation, but within the larger pattern it makes sense. Absent context, it would mean initiating a church service, or more colloquially the music or gravitas a church service brings.